# uniqueidentifier in Sql Server database - how to generate in Java environment?

Tags: java, sql-server, guid, uniqueidentifier

I have a database table that uses Sql Server 2005's uniqueidentifier column.

I know how to create GUIDs in C#...

```
string newid = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

However, the application that is inserting into this database is running Java.

Is there a way to generate Sql-Server-compatible GUIDs using Java code?

(NOTE: generating the GUIDs on the Sql Server side is not an option in this case)

Is this - http://johannburkard.de/software/uuid/ - equivalent to the C# version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not simply use the built in class [java.util.UUID](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html), assuming you are using at least Java 1.5

Answer (score 2):

The code you linked ought to work fine. For kicks, here's another implementation with some good documentation to boot. http://jug.safehaus.org/Home

GUID's are a pretty well defined phenomenon, typically involving a unique machine identifier and the current time and then a bunch of randomness. Anybody who has taken the time to write a GUID library ought to have spent enough time on it to be much better at it than you or I are, so using a library is the right choice. The code I linked has a bunch of links to the IETF specs etc, so I think that's a pretty good sign that they did their due diligence.

See http://www.opengroup.org/dce/info/draft-leach-uuids-guids-01.txt